# How to display Search Input using framework in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material UI, I wanted to create search bar inputfield at the right hand-side in Card Header but I couldn't able to display that. it is not displaying anything.

Here is the Code:

```
<Card>
  <CardHeader
    avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">AJ</Avatar>}
    search={
       <TextField placeholder="Search" margin="normal" />
        // <TextField
        //   id="standard-search"
        //   label="Search field"
        //   type="search"
        // />
        // <IconButton>
        // <SearchIcon/>
        // </IconButton>
      }
      action={
        <IconButton aria-label="settings">
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
      }
  />
</Card>
```

Can anyone help in this Query?

Comment: Sir, I am commenting your Post because you made another one today; and I spent considerable time preparing a full codesanbox for you and then found that you deleted the entire Post. Please consider that the post we make in stackoverflow; even if they don't help you, they may help someone else! I notified the moderators about your doing. It is discouraging for everyone in the community. Have a nice coding!

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI - Sorry Sir, unfortunately it got clicked on delete option instead of Edit, I'll right away search for deleted post and will make it resume because my query is not yet solved. Even i have updated my query with the new snapshot. Please consider my apology for unknowingly doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the props **title** instead, refer to [card-header api](https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/)

> type: node
>   The content of the Card Title.

[image]

```
<CardHeader
  avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">AJ</Avatar>}
  title={
    <TextField
      placeholder="Search"
      margin="normal"
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
    />
  }
  action={
    <IconButton aria-label="settings">
      <MoreVertIcon />
    </IconButton>
  }
/>
```

Comment: But i'm using `title` prop for Name purpose and `subheader` for showing active purpose

Comment: @Arunya You are free to write both your `title` and this `TextField` inside the props, the type is `node`, so you only need to make it a single JSX component and it's all set